# Functoriality of Hochschild cohomology for Drinfeld quotients

Tags: homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, differential-graded-algebras

Let $C$ be a dg category and $C \to D$ a Drinfeld localization. Is there an induced pushforward map on $\operatorname{HH}^*(C) \to \operatorname{HH}^*(D)$, where $\operatorname{HH}^*$ denotes the Hochschild cohomology?

Comment: I think so, by combining Keller's limited functoriality for functors which are fully faithful on the level of derived categories (\S4 of https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/publ/dih.pdf), and Drinfeld's result that the derived category of $D$ sits in the derived category of $C$ (proposition 4.6(ii) from his dg quotients paper). Is this what you are looking for? I was a bit surprised to see it covariantly, but this is what you get apparently, because one uses the _restriction_ functor to get the fully faithful functor on the derived level.